# what is wrong with json response

Tags: python, json

**json response which is working  correctly :**

```
obj = urllib.urlopen("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Fight Club")
response_str = obj.read()
response_json = simplejson.loads(response_str)
```

above code making the json request which looks like :

```
{
    "Title":"Fight Club",
    "Year":"1999",
    "Rated":"R",
    "Released":"15 Oct 1999",
     ......
    "Response":"True"
}
```

so i can sleep now... but

**json response which is not working  correctly :**

```
obj = urllib.urlopen("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")
response_str = obj.read()
response_json = simplejson.loads(response_str)
```

above code making the json request which looks like :

```
{

    "items": [
        {
            "question_id": 18384375,
            "answer_id": 18388044,
            "creation_date": 1377195687,
            "last_activity_date": 1377195687,
            "score": 0,
            "is_accepted": false,
            "owner": {
                "user_id": 1745001,
                "display_name": "Ed Morton",
                "reputation": 10453,
                "user_type": "registered",
                "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/99a3ebae89496eb16afe453aae97f5be?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
                "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton"
            }
        },
        {
            "question_id": 18387447,
            "answer_id": 18388040,
            "creation_date": 1377195667,
            "last_activity_date": 1377195667,
            "score": 0,
            "is_accepted": false,
            "owner": {
                "user_id": 2494429,
                "display_name": "kpark91",
                "reputation": 140,
                "user_type": "registered",
                "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d903a03e7c5b6d9b21ff598c632de575?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
                "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/2494429/kpark91"
            }
        }

       ]
}
```

returns

```
JSONDecodeError at /
No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

instead of using simplejson i tried json which gave following error :

```
ValueError at /
No JSON object could be decoded
```

**what i tried and failed:**

*I tried my questions's answers on stackoverflow having same problem but none of them gave clear cut solution although every one helped me in some way*

1) i checked whether json content encoding is correct or not

```
>>obj.info()

Content-Type: application/json; 
charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2398
```

2) i decoded the response_str in utf-8

```
json.loads(response_str).decode("utf-8")
```

3) i used jsonlint to check format of json response

```
Parse error on line 1:

^
Expecting '{', '['
```

surprisingly following link of rescued my sleep. 
[JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

Basically i was using exact code to get json response in both cases , but whats wrong with the second json response, only difference i noticed that the structure of second json response was different from first one.

please provide explanation to understand the issue.

Comment: The server is returning the response in gzipped encoding.  E.g., on the command line `curl 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow' | gunzip` will show you the JSON that you're expecting.  I'm not a Python user, but apparently the `requests` library that some of the answers are mentioning handle the gzipped content correctly.

Comment: There are some relevant questions about urllib[2] and gzipped content on SO:  [Does python urllib2 will automaticly uncompress gzip data from fetch webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3947120/1281433); [urlopen trouble while trying to download a gzip file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18146389/1281433); [Why I got messy characters while opening url using urllib2?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7231280/1281433); [Convert gzipped data fetched by urllib2 to HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1704754/1281433); [Python urllib2 parse html problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6899273/1281433).

Comment: Hey, added a picture-video gif to help you out. If you choose to work with requests, you will get better sleep, as alecxe has promised! :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me give you some advice. Using `urllib` is great and all, but you will run into a lot of trouble. So, let me save you the pain, and just lead you to [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html). Its the best way to deal with url requests.

This short IDLE session will demonstrate:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

To install it, just go to your command prompt and `pip install requets`. requets is free and open source, and its written in pure python so the installation is simple.

Here is a video to demonstrate:
[image]

Your particular problem:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

One way to have a good sleep is to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests
import simplejson

response = requests.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")
response_json = simplejson.loads(response.text)
print response_json
```

No errors, just works.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are mentioning the `requests` library, but based on some other answers on StackOverflow, it seems like you could also just modify your code to include the GZip decompression. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6899402/1281433), I think this would be:

```
import StringIO, gzip 

obj = urllib.urlopen("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/answersorder=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")
data = StringIO.StringIO(obj.read())
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=data)
response_json = simplejson.loads(gzipper.read())
```